# Order of elements is messed up after using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, gps, sql-order-by

I drive the same route daily. Its a roundtrip ending at the starting point. I have collected data from several trips and put it into a MySQL table.

The columns are:
     trip_id, time_of_day_in_seconds, latitude, longitude, speed, acceleration, ...

I would like to compute typical (speed, acceleration,...) values for every GPS-point (latitude, longitude) of my route and have the result sorted in order of appearance of the GPS-points.

I tried the following with the GROUP BY function:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, avg(speed)
FROM vextended
GROUP BY latitude, longitude
;
```

And the problem with the result is: the order of the GPS-points it messed up! They are not sorted in order of appearence!

How would it be possible to achieve that?

Kind Regards

Theo

Comment: Specify `order by` clause explicitly. Other wise `order` of results is not guaranteed.

Comment: Yes, the problem is, by what should I order the result elements?

Comment: If you want to sort result by speed, then use `order by 3` meaning sort by 3rd column of result set.

Comment: I want to have the result sorted in order of appearance of the GPS-points.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to define a second table `routes` (that defines each journey by a sequence of waypoints) and then identify the coordinates to which each piece of collected data belongs via an FK into that new table.

Thus, assuming that every instance of the journey produces records with *identical* coordinates:

1. Define and populate a new table `routes`:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE routes (
     route_id    BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     waypoint    BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     coordinates POINT           NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (route_id, waypoint_number)
   ) SELECT   1, @c:=@c+1, POINT(latitude, longitude)
     FROM     vextended, (SELECT @c:=0) init
     WHERE    journey_id = ?  /* filter for one journey only */
   ```

   MySQL offers no guarantee over the order in which waypoints will be thusly defined, however you *should* find that they're defined in the same order as their respective record's entry in the PK of the `vextended` table (which I suspect is what you're after); you should nevertheless manually inspect (and adjust) the `waypoint` values such that the route is defined correctly.
2. Alter the existing table to reference this new one:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE vextended
     ADD COLUMN route_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     ADD COLUMN waypoint BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;

   UPDATE vextended v
     JOIN routes    r
       ON r.coordinates = POINT(v.latitude, v.longitude)
      AND r.route_id = 1
   SET    v.route_id = r.route_id,
          v.waypoint = r.waypoint;

   ALTER TABLE vextended
     ADD FOREIGN KEY (route_id, waypoint) REFERENCES routes (route_id, waypoint),
     DROP COLUMN latitude,
     DROP COLUMN longitude;
   ```
3. Query using your new waypoint data:

   ```
   SELECT   waypoint,
            r.coordinates,
            X(r.coordinates) AS latitude,
            Y(r.coordinates) AS longitude,
            AVG(v.speed)
   FROM     vextended v JOIN routes r USING (route_id, waypoint)
   WHERE    route_id = 1
   GROUP BY waypoint
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will work through this one, though it will take some time.